# Login page with express and create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication

I'm working on a project using `express.js` and `create-react-app`.
The basic structure of the project is:

```
/.
|-- express-backend(:3001)
|---|---react-frontend:(:3000)
```

The express backend is serving on the port 3001 while the frontend is serving on the 3000. I don't have any problem in making this work, since I'm redirecting backend requests using `proxy` in the `package.json`

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
```

The only problem comes when I'm trying to redirect the user on a login page using `app.use("/login", login)`. 
I'd like to redirect users to a `login.ejs` page when he is on the url `localhost:3000/login`.
I'm only able to visualize the page when I visit `localhost:3001/login`.

How can I redirect the user to the static page `login.ejs` when he is on `localhost:3000/login`?

(I'm new on express, if you can give me an explanation with the answer I'd be very grateful)

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use("/login", function(req,res){
  res.redirect("login");
});
```

Now this login.ejs page should be available public folder which is accessible to user.

Comment: I can only open the login page if I'm on the url `localhost:3001/login`. In that way the login is shown correctly.
But I want to show the page when the user is on the port 3000. How can I redirect it?

Comment: you need to create proxy server that will run on port 3000 and from that server redirect all request to 3001.Please refer this https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy

Comment: This looks interesting! Thanks

Comment: I was looking to http-proxy documentation. Isn't it the same that using the "proxy":"localhost:3001" parameter in the package.json?